# Is the protected route I'm currently in preventing the user from going back to the Home component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks, material-ui

I can't figure out how I can navigate the user to the `Home` component when logging out.  The API works fine as I've tested it out.

However, I'm not sure how to use the `logout` method in the current context in order for the user to logout successfully and return to the `Home` component.

The current behavior is weirdly incorrect as when I click on `Logout`, it navigates to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` but the `Grid` component goes blank instead of redirecting to `Home` component.

If I manually type in `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` in the browser's search bar, it correctly redirects to the `Home` component.

I'm assuming this has something to do with the the Protected route.  How can I fix this?

Here's ProtectedRoute.js:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Redirect, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const ProtectedRoute = (props) =>  {
    const user = localStorage.getItem('token');

    if(!user) {
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }

    return <Route {...props} />;
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Here'a App.js:

```
const App = () => {
return (
    <>
        <Router>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <ProtectedRoute path="/gallery" component={Grid} />
            </Switch>
        </Router>
    </>
   );
}
```

Here's Navbar.js:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
let authToken = localStorage.getItem('token');
let history = useHistory();

const logout = () => {
        const headers = {
            "Accept": 'application/json',
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
        };

        const data = "";

        axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/logout', data, {headers})
            .then(resp => {
                localStorage.removeItem('token');
                history.push('/');
            }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        });
}


<Button onClick={logout}>Logout</Button>
```

Comment: Is this the whole code of Navbar.js? it doesn't seem like a valid React component

Comment: @NirG it's just the code that pertains to the issue I'm facing.  There's no need to post an entire component.

Comment: what's your react-router-dom version?

Comment: @MOLLY the version is 5.3.4

Comment: Can you provide a online editor like codesandbox, the code seens ok lol.

Comment: Can you show what you are doing in `Home` and `Grid` components?

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell what the exact issue is here, but here's what works: Instead of returning a redirect in ProtectedRoute, you can change it to be `window.location.href = "/";`

or

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate("/");
```

also, make sure your post request is not failing, as that will cause the redirect not to happen either. I would also suggest using the current version of react-router-dom.

Comment: Tried your first suggestion, still getting the same result